# Issue sorting (in decrescent order) bar plot the top 30 values of my dataframe

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I am having problems sorting (decrescent) the top 30 values of a bar plot using Seaborn. I'm using some recommendations that I found here but I'm still having the issue.

My current script looks like this:

```
c_firms_2008a = c_firms_2008.sort_values(['diversity'], ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True).head(n=20)

ax = sns.catplot(x="code_city", y="diversity", kind="bar", data=c_firms_2008a, aspect=16/8, palette="GnBu_d")
ax.set(xlabel='Industries', ylabel='VAT Generated, US Dollars')
ax.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
```

my resulting graph looks like this...

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try printing `c_firms_2008a ` after sorting and see if the values are actually sorted

Comment: @Bazingaa, I did that and they are sorted.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: I found a better solution than what I had original written below**

`catplot` doesn't honor the sorting of the dataframe. Therefore, to ensure proper ordering of your bars, use the `order=` parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': np.arange(10), 'val':np.random.normal(size=(10,))})
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='val', ascending=False)
ax = sns.catplot(x="code", y="val", kind="bar", data=df_sorted, order=df_sorted.code, aspect=16/8, palette="GnBu_d")
```

[image: enter code here]

**Original answer:**

It looks like `catplot` always sorts the x-axis if they are numbers (or look like numbers). The (far from perfect) solution is to transform your x-categories into something that cannot be casts to numbers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': np.arange(10), 'val':np.random.normal(size=(10,))})
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='val', ascending=False)
```

this doesn't work (as you've found out):

```
ax = sns.catplot(x="code", y="val", kind="bar", data=df_sorted, aspect=16/8, palette="GnBu_d")
```

[image]

converting to string doesn't seem to be enough

```
df_sorted2 = df_sorted.copy()
df_sorted2['code'] = df_sorted2.code.astype(str)
ax = sns.catplot(x="code", y="val", kind="bar", data=df_sorted2, aspect=16/8, palette="GnBu_d")
```

[image]

this does work

```
df_sorted3 = df_sorted.copy()
df_sorted3['code'] = df_sorted3['code'].map(lambda x: '#{:d}'.format(x))
ax = sns.catplot(x="code", y="val", kind="bar", data=df_sorted3, aspect=16/8, palette="GnBu_d")
```

[image]